# Shell - how i can use a variable in sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I'm having a problem when use a variable in sed command.

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Declaracao de variaveis
dominio=$1
host=$2

#Configuração do Varnish
varnish_config=$(cat <<-END
if (req.http.host ~ "$dominio") {
        set req.backend_hint = $host;
        return (pass);
}
END
)

sed '51i\'"${varnish_config}" $PWD/teste
```

The error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `\n\\` to each line of `varnish_config`. shell will expand this to "new line" and `\`. If in the end of line will be `\` sed will concatenate next line to current one.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Declaracao de variaveis
dominio=$1
host=$2

#Configuração do Varnish
varnish_config=$(cat <<-END
if (req.http.host ~ "$dominio") {\n\\
        set req.backend_hint = $host;\n\\
        return (pass);\n\\
}
END
)

sed '51i\'"${varnish_config}" $PWD/teste
```

Comment: Pretty sure this introduces an empty line after each of the inserted lines. Just escaping the linebreak with ``\`` should be enough.

Comment: Yes, but then inserted text on file will be in one line.

Comment: That sed command is not supported on Mac OSX. Can you please provide the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Going the detour via a shell variable and sed (which is not suited for multiline substitutions) is tedious. The way to insert a file into another file at some position is to use a capable editor, like `ex`:

```
$ seq 5 > 5.txt
$ seq 10 > 10.txt
$ cat 10.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ printf '6\nr 5.txt\nw\nq\n' | ex 10.txt
$ cat 10.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
10
```

The `ex` comands are:

```
6            set position to line 6
r 5.txt      read file 5.txt
w            write file
q            quit
```